# How to create an n-dimensional array using given data using numpy ndarray

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array

I am trying to cast my data into an ndarray. Although I get what I want but while testing I am not able to figure out why it gives me this output.

I get the output:

```
np.ndarray(shape = (2,1),buffer = np.array([1,2,3,4]))
array([[4.24399158e-314],
   [8.48798317e-314]])
```

However for this block I am able to cast my random numbers the way I want.

```
def x_mat(n,m):
   np.random.seed(0)
   randoms = np.random.normal(size=n*m)
   print(randoms)
   rand_mat = np.ndarray(shape = (n,m),buffer = randoms)
   return(rand_mat)
x_mat(5,2)
```

to give:

```
[ 1.76405235  0.40015721  0.97873798  2.2408932   1.86755799 -0.97727788 
  0.95008842 -0.15135721 -0.10321885  0.4105985 ]


array([[ 1.76405235,  0.40015721],
       [ 0.97873798,  2.2408932 ],
       [ 1.86755799, -0.97727788],
       [ 0.95008842, -0.15135721],
       [-0.10321885,  0.4105985 ]])
```

If someone can help me understand this behavior. It does the correct thing in the second case but I find the first case as something that is not straight forward. Why is the first case the way it is?

Comment: Why are you trying to use `np.ndarray`?  Ordinary mortals don't normally need it.

Comment: The `dtype` of `randoms` is `float`, same as the default for `ndarray`.

Comment: @hpaulj - What would you suggest to use ? I usually need 2-d  arrays mostly for linear algebra computations. np.matrix ? I had a feeling they are moving away from np.matrix  in future versions and some functions have become deprecated for np.matrix

Comment: `np.matrix` doesn't add any computational power; never did.  Its `*` multiply is matrix multiplication, but so is `np.dot` and `matmul` (and the `@` operator).  It's just as easy to make 2d `ndarray` - just use the `np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])` syntax or `reshape`.  You rarely need `ndarray`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [164]: x = np.array([1,2,3,4])
In [165]: x.__array_interface__
Out[165]: 
{'data': (40465184, False),
 'strides': None,
 'descr': [('', '<i8')],
 'typestr': '<i8',
 'shape': (4,),
 'version': 3}
```

The array created with `ndarray` has the same `data` buffer:

```
In [166]: y = np.ndarray(shape = (2,1),buffer = x)
In [167]: y
Out[167]: 
array([[5.e-324],
       [1.e-323]])
In [168]: y.__array_interface__
Out[168]: 
{'data': (40465184, False),        # same as for x
 'strides': None,
 'descr': [('', '<f8')],
 'typestr': '<f8',
 'shape': (2, 1),
 'version': 3}
```

and for an array using the int dtype:

```
In [169]: z = np.ndarray(shape = (2,1),buffer = x, dtype=int)
In [170]: z.__array_interface__
Out[170]: 
{'data': (40465184, False),
 'strides': None,
 'descr': [('', '<i8')],
 'typestr': '<i8',
 'shape': (2, 1),
 'version': 3}
```

In fact we don't need to pass `x` as the buffer argument, just its `x.data` attribute:

```
In [171]: np.ndarray(shape = (2,1), buffer = x.data, dtype=int)
Out[171]: 
array([[1],
       [2]])
```

Because of the shared data buffer, modifications to `z` appear in `x` as well
    In [172]: z[:] *= 2
    In [173]: z
    Out[173]: 
    array([[2],
           [4]])
    In [174]: x
    Out[174]: array([2, 4, 3, 4])

and `y`:

```
In [175]: y
Out[175]: 
array([[1.e-323],
       [2.e-323]])
```

With an `offset` we can make an array that selects a different part of the data buffer:

```
In [178]: w=np.ndarray(shape = (2,1), buffer = x.data, dtype=int, offset=8)
In [179]: w
Out[179]: 
array([[4],
       [3]])
```

But normally we don't use `ndarray` to do this.  Instead we use slicing to get a `view`, with `reshape` if needed:

```
In [181]: x[1:3].reshape(2,1)
Out[181]: 
array([[4],
       [3]])
```

---

You can construct the equivalent of `rand_mat` with `randoms.reshape(n,m)` or `np.random.normal(size=(n,m))`.

`ndarray` is normally only needed when the `buffer` comes from so other source, something that isn't already an `ndarray` which can be reshaped or `viewed`.

Comment: Really helpful. I did not know about the interface and x.data concept. This has broadened my understanding of np.array data construct in python.

Comment: Keep in mind that we normally use `np.array` to make arrays.  `ndarray` is only for specialized situations.

Comment: Does ndarray perform a copy of the passed data or creates reference?

Comment: @nullspace, are you asking about the `buffer` parameter of `np.ndarray`?  Read the docs..

Comment: > data: buffer, Python buffer object pointing to the start of the array’s data.

I'm assuming this means it's a reference?

Comment: That `40465184` value shows that all of the `ndarray` objects use the same databuffer as `x`. @nullspace.  No copying

Comment: looks like this is only true if you're explicitly passing the buffer attribute. by default, it looks like a copy. i.e np.ndarray(somedata) is a copy vs np.ndarray(shape=(2,1), buffer=somedata)

Comment: @nullspace, the first argument to `ndarray` is a `positional` (no keyword), and is the `shape`.  Then the `dtype`, and third the `buffer`.  For clairity you should supply the keyword for all arguments except the first. Generally it's better to use `np.array` instead of `ndarray`, unless you are trying to do something special with the data buffer (such as creating an array from some different class of object).

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.html) on `ndarray` with the signature.

`ndarray(shape, dtype, buffer, offset, strides, order)`

> 1. If `buffer` is None, then only shape, dtype, and order are used.
> 2. If `buffer` is an object exposing the buffer interface, then all keywords are interpreted.

Seems to be that for the first example, even though the `buffer` is an `np.array` of integers, `ndarray` interprets it as a different type. You have to give it the *optional* argument `dtype = int` so that the ndarray explicitly know its elements are of type integer.

```
np.ndarray(shape = (2,1), dtype = int, buffer = np.array([1,2,3,4]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's consider your first example:

```
n = np.ndarray(shape=(2,2), buffer= np.array([1,12,3,4,5,6]), dtype=int, order='F') 
#Note that order is 'F' here and the the order changes from above. 
print(n)

Output: 
[[ 1  3]
 [12  4]]
```

Observe since buffer is provided, now it looks further into shape, dtype, and order. Let's change the order to 'c' and see what happens.

```
n = np.ndarray(shape=(2,2), buffer= np.array([1,12,3,4,5,6]), dtype=int, order='C') 
#Note that order is 'C' here.
print(n)

[[ 1 12]
 [ 3  4]]
```

Now, let's make the buffer to 'None'. Then it simply takes 0's and 1's values and applies the shape and dtype to it.

```
n = np.ndarray(shape=(2,2), buffer= None, dtype=int, order='F') 
print(n)

Output:
[[1 1]
 [1 0]]
```

So to conclude, whenever there is buffer takes an array. It has to apply dtype, order and shape to it. When it is None, buffer is simply not applicable. Hope this helps!:)